# wp_schedule_event didn't work

Tags: cron

It will work if I give specific post id.It didn’t work if I give $post->ID. Why?

Here my code:

```
add_action( 'wp', 'delete_expired_coupons_daily' );
function delete_expired_coupons_daily() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'update_expired_post_status' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'update_expired_post_status');
    }
}
function update_expired_field(){     
 global $post;
 $postid=$post->ID;
              $my_post = array(
                             'ID'           => $postid,
                             'post_status'   => 'expired',
                         );
              wp_update_post( $my_post );

}
add_action( 'update_expired_post_status', 'update_expired_field', 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Cron fires outside of the standard WordPress loop, so `$post` will not be filled with any post-related data when the function is called. It should be obvious, then, that providing an ID directly isn't referencing the non-existent `$post` variable which is why it works in that scenario.

The best way to set post_statuses to expired is to change your function to something that loads posts which need to be expired and loops through them, using WP_Query:

```
function update_expired_field() {
    $today = getdate();
    $query = new WP_Query( 'meta_query' => array(
            'key'     => 'your_expire_meta_key',
            'value'   => $today['year'] . '-' . $today['month'] . '-' . $today['mday'],
            'type'    => 'DATE',
            'compare' => '<=',
        ),
        'fields' => 'ids',
    );

    foreach( $query->posts as $postid ) {
        wp_update_post( array(
            'ID'          => $postid,
            'post_status' => 'expired',
        ) );
    }
}
```

In the code I've shown querying the meta_key field from the database for a key called 'your_expire_meta_key', which needs to have values of the date you want the posts to expire in the format YYYY-MM-DD. We compare that date field against today's date to determine which posts need expiring. The `'fields' => 'ids'` tells WP_Query to only return post IDs so that we run as fast as possible. Finally we loop-through each post ID and update the relevant post to expired status.